# How to minimize a single Windows application form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. I currently have a button in the startup form(Form1) that loads up Form2. What I would like to do is have Form1 become minimized and only show Form2 once it is told to load so that Form1 is not in the background while Form 2 is shown.

So far I have tried things such as:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

but the problem I'm having is that it causes Form2 to become minimized as well. Is there a way to specifically cause only Form1 to be affected or work around this problem?

below you will find my code, I may have made some mistakes!

```
  Form2 add = new Form2();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        add.ShowDialog();
```

I had also tried putting the windowstate behind the showdialog  but it may not work because it will only execute after the dialog is done working.

Comment: This code does not replicate the issue. I can show one form while minimizing the other just fine. Please show the code block where you show your form and minimize this one.

Comment: @Equalsk I have edited my post!

Comment: It's because you're using ShowDialog, have you tried Show?

Comment: @Equalsk I have the same problem with Show()

Comment: Correct me if I'm being ignorant, as I usually write in just VB instead of C#, but why are we declaring a new instance of form2? Could you not, instead, just write out "Form2.Show()" , and then "this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized" ?

Comment: @DougRobinson No, you must instantiate the form first as OP has shown.

Comment: Oh... Is that different in C# than in VB? I wasn't aware.

Comment: Not sure, haven't touched VB in years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to two things.

1. You're using [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) which launches Form2 as a modal dialog. Hint: Go read about modal dialogs
2. You need to minimize *after* showing Form2

Change your code to this:

```
var add = new Form2();
add.Show();
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I have a poor background with C# so I was assuming the window was "running" when shown and it wouldn't run minimized properly. Thanks, it works!